# Adding informative statusbar to fullscreen terminal window

Tags: macos, terminal, statusbar, tmux

Briefly:
I would love to add a status bar that sticks to either the bottom or top of my terminal window that provides glancible information (e.g. battery life, signal strength, email count, $PROMT_COMMAND, etc.). Essentially, this will allow the terminal to be opened up to fullscreen and have all the information I could possibly want easily glancible while letting me continue all of my necessary terminal work as normal. I use a mac primarily, but would prefer a *nix compatible solution.

More detail (and what I already tried):
I am a big terminal user and only recently (within a day or two) started using tmux, so I understand that many of you may suggest that I try to use a multiplexer like screen or tmux. While tmux is starting to get very useful to me, it has it's limitations such as a limit to a single-row status bar, which is not ideal since I would want to keep the tab's bar clean without half of it being eaten up by information. Also, I would want to add $PROMPT_COMMAND which displays the current directory, and that could easily eat up most of the status bar depending on where I am in the system.

Also, I tried screen for a bit, which let's you have a hardstatus and a caption which is close to what I want, but it's development seems to have halted. Furthermore, the patch for vertical  split panes messes up the graphics of a two-row status bar (very ugly).

Therefore, I think it would be preferable to have a background process running that updates a status bar on part of the screen above my multiplexer ... unless of course tmux has a multi-row status bar implementation that I haven't figured out yet.

I would love to hear about any of your possible solutions, or even your own personal setups if you think it works well for you. Thank you all for any possible help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. You could run tmux inside tmux (with different configurations; you can use -f to specify a configuration file.)
2. You could use the tab title, though that's probably not wide enough to include everything you want.  (Even if there's only one tab, you can show the tab bar in fullscreen mode).  You need to tell tmux to pass the title through; see `set set-titles` and `set set-titles-string`.

I'd suggest you use both - put the current directory in the tab title and all the other status info in a separate line maintained by tmux, that way you can just skip the second part when you're not using a full-screen terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! First, I was originally using the tab-title, but as you said, it's too small to contain the info I want. Alternatively, I had considered this idea (running tmux inside tmux or screen). This is probably the best option. Some problems I see, and don't know an easy solution:

1. won't key bindings get confused between the nested tmux windows?
2. is there a way to have the initial tmux session automatically open the sub-tmux instance?
3. does this affect detachment of the windows?

Comment: 1. You can change the tmux command prefix (`set -g prefix`). 2. Sure, you can start tmux with something like `tmux new-session -n tmux 'TMUX= exec tmux'` (of course, provide different config files with -f for each). 3. The outer tmux would exit when you detach the inner tmux, since all (1) of its clients are gone.

Comment: Wow, I've been doing a lot of trials of this and there is certainly potential for this to be the optimum solution. However, I found that in order to access the prefix of the nested tmux-sessions, C-b must be performed 2-times for the 2nd nested tmux (only works for 2). This is because they each inherit the parent's source-file. So, if I write: `tmux -f outer.conf new 'TMUX= exec tmux -f inner.conf'` they all take `source-file outer.conf`. I cannot seem to specify a separate conf-file. Interesting note: if I ssh a remote server and run tmux, it works. Any ideas for a local solution?

Comment: Ahah! I found that the `-L socket-name` option will let me create more than one server (and therefore more than one `source-file`). This will get me to what I need. When I create a script to properly create the session and reattach (to both), I will post my results. Thanks a lot for the incredibly helpful hints and discussion!

Comment: Sorry, missed that—you need to give tmux another socket to use.  So something like `tmux -f outer.conf new 'TMUX= exec tmux -L inner -f inner.conf'` should work.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what is needed. Therer's only one more thing I could add to this discussion for others coming across this (or for me if I forget). If you detach using the inner-tmux-prefix, it will exit, but if you detach using the outer-tmux-prefix, it will detach and can be reattached preserving both inner and outer tmux sessions. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have battery info in mine,

You can get copies of the files you'll need at

https://github.com/richo/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf
and
https://github.com/richo/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/battery

(Make sure that battery is executable and in your PATH)

It'll show you battery percentage in blue (charging), red (discharging) or not at all (fully charged)