# Auto-update tmux status bar with active pane pwd

Tags: tmux

In tmux, the status bar normally shows the current working directory of a pane in the window list. If I have for example two panes in a window, and the two panes have different working directories, is it possible to automatically update the status bar with the current working directory of the pane I’m currently focused on?

To clarify, if I have a window with two panes, and the first pane is in `~` and the second pane is in `~/Sites`, I would like the window list in the status bar to say **1:~** when I am focused on the first pane, and **1:~/Sites** when I am focused on the second pane.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Tmux pane PWD at the prompt

There are several ways that you can do this. I do it myself. The easiest and most customisable way is to set a global variable that tmux can access.

First add this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file, to set the PWD variable after every prompt:

```
# create a global per-pane variable that holds the pane's PWD
export PS1=$PS1'$( [ -n $TMUX ] && tmux setenv -g TMUX_PWD_$(tmux display -p "#D" | tr -d %) $PWD)'
```

Now, make a script that displays this variable such as `~/bin/display_tmux_pane_pwd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux showenv -g TMUX_PWD_$(tmux display -p "#D" | tr -d %)  | sed 's/^.*=//'
```

All that is left is to add this to the satis-bar in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g status-left '#(~/bin/display_tmux_pane_pwd.sh)'
```

It may take awhile to update after switching panes, so you can change that with this command. By default it updates every 15 seconds, this will make it 5 seconds. Change it as you like.

```
set -g status-interval 5
```

---

### Tmux-pane PWD in other programs

Sometimes it is useful to open up a pane or window and immediately execute a program instead of booting up another shell (e.g. `tmux new-window vim`). This way, when you close that program you also close the window. Unfortunately, the way I describe above requires a prompt in order to broadcast the status of PWD. However, in many programs, you can work around this fairly easily. Here's an example of what is in my `.vimrc` file so that vim updates the PWD status whenever it changes buffers.

```
if exists("$TMUX")
    " Get the environment variable
    let tmux_pane_name_cmd = 'tmux display -p \#D'
    let tmux_pane_name = substitute(system(g:tmux_pane_name_cmd), "\n", "", "")
    let tmux_env_var = "TMUX_PWD_" . substitute(g:tmux_pane_name, "%", "", "")
    unlet tmux_pane_name tmux_pane_name_cmd
    function! BroadcastTmuxCwd()
        let filename = substitute(expand("%:p:h"), $HOME, "~", "")
        let output = system("tmux setenv -g ".g:tmux_env_var." ".l:filename)
    endfunction
    autocmd BufEnter * call BroadcastTmuxCwd()
endif
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be working for me. The status bar doesn’t update until after I do something with the prompt. Is there an event that can be listened to when I switch focus to another pane in tmux?

Comment: Hmm… This might not have worked because there is an unmatched `"` in that line I placed in my `.zshrc`. Not exactly sure where I should place it though.

Comment: Oops, the PS1 was a little wonky and had excessive quotation marks. Try it this way, I cannot check it just yet unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, and yes, this requires the prompt to be printed at least once. If you start a pane executing a program and not a prompt then you will not get anything unless you set this variable from that program. I can give my .vimrc that does this if you want.

Comment: @JezenThomas , Just wanted to let you know I finally fixed the PS1 part (should now be compatible with bash and zsh). Also, I added a note about implementing it in other programs and an example for `vim`

Comment: Hi @scicalculator is there any way to prompt the PWD to status-bar in an ssh session? For example, ssh to a server inside a tmux session, how can I see the remote path in this tmux session?

Comment: @worldterminator , yes, in principle this is possible. I have previously gotten this to work using tmux v1.7 a long time ago. Recently I have not been using my code base for tmux modification, but If my memory serves me, I think it was through a sneaky tmux inside tmux. Perhaps this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004700/adding-informative-statusbar-to-fullscreen-terminal-window . Good luck!

Comment: @worldterminator ,this may help more: http://superuser.com/questions/322896/tmux-sharing-current-window-title-t-from-within-nested-tmux-sessions/323319#323319

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the previous answer, I'd like to add you don't have to rely on the status-interval option. Waiting to see the change isn't really elegant. You can manually update the status bar on events with:

```
tmux refresh-client -S
```

I use this option after pane/window/session switching. In my tmux config you will find for instance to switch panes:

```
bind -r k select-pane -U\; refresh-client -S
bind -r j select-pane -D\; refresh-client -S
bind -r l select-pane -R\; refresh-client -S
bind -r h select-pane -L\; refresh-client -S
```

I have previously posted on this: [manually refresh status bar](https://superuser.com/a/697565/266863)

Answer (score 6):

This is another way to do this.

## Working ENV:

### OS

- OSX 10.14.5

### Terminal

- Alacritty 0.3.3 - https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty
- iTerm2 3.2.9 - https://iterm2.com/
- Apple Terminal 2.9.5

### Tmux

- tmux 2.9a

### ~/.tmux.config

```sh
set -g status-interval 1
set-window-option -g window-status-separator ""
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format " *#{b:pane_current_path} "
set-window-option -g window-status-format " #{b:pane_current_path} "
```

### Note

- Shows pwd `#{b:pane_current_path}`
- Shows full path `#{pane_current_path}`

### Make home display as ~

```
path="#(if [[ $HOME == #{pane_current_path} ]]; then echo \"~\" ; else echo #{b:pane_current_path}; fi)"


set-window-option -g window-status-separator ""
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format " $path "
set-window-option -g window-status-format " $path "
```

### tmux plugin

[tmux-space-theme](https://github.com/casonadams/tmux-space-theme)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the current window name to reflect the directory name, here is a modified version of the original answer that does not require calling a script from tmux and updates instantly:

```
export PS1=$PS1'$( [ -n $TMUX ] && tmux rename-window $(basename $PWD))'
```

Note that this means that you can't display the current process name any longer. It is of little value for me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use `automatic-rename-format`

The following is an example of limit 10 chars, and it checks for current command, or current path.

```
set -g automatic-rename on

set-option -g automatic-rename-format "#{?#{==:#{pane_current_command},zsh},#{=-10:#{b:pane_current_path}},#{=10:#{pane_current_command}}}"
```

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this to my .zshrc (or .bashrc):

`cd() {
    builtin cd $1
    tmux refresh-client -S
}`

Then binding `tmux refresh-client -S` to pane switching as others have done.