# how to make tcsh shell title show full path of current directory?

Tags: shell, tmux, tcsh

how to make tcsh shell title show full path of current directory?

my current konsole looks like:

```
[user@shell curr_dir]$
```

I want it to look like:

```
[user@shell absolute path to curr_dir]$
```

I use tmux, could any one suggest how to show full path of the current directory in the tmux status bar instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> cd /etc/defaults
> set prompt = "%n@ %/ % "
user@/etc/defaults %
```

`tmux`is more complicated since the pane status does not refresh on events unless you configure it to do so. See [Auto-update tmux status bar with active pane pwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200589/auto-update-tmux-status-bar-with-active-pane-pwd)  for tips on how to tackle this task.